# #include won't load header in C

Tags: c, include

I've recently been trying to program some simple code for the NES. I wrote a batch file that takes the file I wrote in C and turns it into a `.nes` file but every time I run it, my C file can't load a header. Here's the script that's causing problems.

```
#include <nes.h>
```

Note that I have very little knowledge of C but I'd still like to know what's happening.

Comment: I think something went wrongnwith your post.  Edit it, and use the buttons above the edit window.

Comment: Also consider adding your working code to see if there is a problem in it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You have not provided enough code (yet) to allow anyone to help you. Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You mention a batch file; does that mean you're working on Windows?  Where is NES installed?  What compilation command line are you using?  Without at least some of this information, your question will be closed as unanswerable.

Comment: If nes.h is a user written header file then try #include "nes.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is "nes.h" located when you run the compiler? if it is in the current directory, then 
  #include "nes.h" 
will do.

otherwise you must tell the compiler in which directory to find it using -I  parameter
  gcc ... -I  ...

Comment: Did what your said and it fixed it. Sorry for the strange post, it was my first time ever using stackoverflow.